# An alias to `\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi`

Tags: macros

I work on a report class full of these wonderful commands:

```
\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
```

My smart idea is the following command:

`newcommand*{\clear}{\if@openright \cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi}`

Does it have any drawback I am am unaware of or may I substitute anywhere it may appear?

Comment: "full"? How many different new-page constructs do you have? using a macro is OK but you may want to use an internal one such as `\@clear` to avoid clashing with other document defined definitions `\clear` is  a name someone might use. That is why class/package commands have `@`

Comment: If the commands are in the class, why bother? If you must use them in the document, there's something wrong with the class.

Comment: Hi, David and egreg. Am I being stalked by entities? Haha. Nevertheless, does it  mean that I need to call it \@command within the class?

Comment: @egreg I bother because I am one of those guys who refactor classes. I must have heard of such weirdos...

Comment: @BrunoPeixoto Assuming your class is named `myclass`, prefix the internal commands with something like `myclass@`, so you'd do `\newcommand{\myclass@clear}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}`. How many times would you use `\myclass@clear`? If five or more, maybe defining `\myclass@clear` might be useful.

Comment: Great. Take a look at https://github.com/alloyha/TheXis/blob/master/thexis.cls with following thought workflow: 1. Search for "\clear" token; 2. See occurrences. I say it is a hand-full. I will take your advice. :-)

Comment: Well, I just made the alterations. Then you will not see "\clear" anymore. :'-(